Insurance underwriting based upon an arrest for a DUI when charges are dropped
If a person is arrested for a DUI but the charges are dropped because of:

The breath analyzer found no alcohol in his system
A blood test did not find any illegal drugs in his system

Would it be legal to deny the person an umbrella insurance policy because of the arrest? Could it be viewed as racist since African Americans are more likely to be arrested than white people?

Umbrella policies are very strict and one can do a lot of protection of assets through home owners insurance, and auto insurance.  Additionally state laws may disallow certain types of assets to be taken in a suit.


Would it be legal to deny the person an umbrella insurance policy
because of the arrest?

This depends upon state insurance law.
The default rule of law in the absence of a specialized insurance law that prohibits it, is that a private individual  can refuse to do business with anyone for any reason that isn't prohibited.
Usually, state insurance laws allow insurance companies to consider only certain factors when underwriting an insurance policy (i.e. deciding whether to let someone buy an insurance policy and deciding what to charge), and the rates charged typically have to be approved in advance by a state insurance regulator.
Being arrested is not a prohibited reason to issue an insurance policy in all states. It may be a prohibited reason in some states.

Could it be viewed as racist since African Americans are more likely
to be arrested than white people?

Racist isn't a legal standard. The legal standard is whether the insurance company intends to discriminate on the basis of race, or some other prohibited reason, in an area where that is prohibited by law.
The fact that a determination is made on a basis that has a disproportionate statistical impact on people of different races does not render it illegal.
One example of this is the insurance company USAA which only offers insurance and other financial products to people who have served honorably in the military, are currently serving in the military, or have close family members who did.
This effectively screens out the vast majority of people with criminal records, people who are incapable of dealing effectively with bureaucracies, high school dropouts, and people in the bottom 15-25% or so of IQ, all of whom are at greatly elevated risks of getting into accidents and needing to make claims, without doing so overtly. The military does their screening for them.
Because the pool of people allowed to do business with USAA screens out such a large share of people who pose elevated risks of losses to USAA on insurance policies and loans, it can offer lower rates to its customers that reflect their lower insurance risks and lower risks of default on loans.
Statistically, this probably has a disproportionate impact on some categories of people that it may be illegal to intentionally discriminate against. But the law tolerates that when it is one step removed and relies on prior screening decisions to accept or reject people made by the government itself.
Financial companies that developed preferred relationship deals with alumni associations of colleges and universities are doing essentially the same thing.
As a business proposition, insurance companies want to distinguish between people who are at higher risk of making a claim and those who are at a lower risk of making a claim, and to charge accordingly based  upon the actuarial prediction of the risk.
Arrests are often used by businesses, rather than convictions, because  arrest data is often easier to obtain and because the business is better off refusing to do business in a case of a "false positive" than doing business with someone who is a higher risk than expected leading to a "false negative".
Someone who is arrested is at higher risk of being guilty of a crime, even if not charged or convicted (e.g. due to a violation of rights by law enforcement or a deferred prosecution agreement or an inability to definitively prove guilt beyond a reasonable doubt). So, statistically, businesses are correct in reasoning that the class of people who have been arrested but not charged or convicted are at higher risk of actually being "criminals" or "bad drivers" than people who are not arrested.
But it is also a product of being lazy and indifferent to the plight of people who are wrongfully arrested. This is why some states in some circumstances prohibit underwriting or hiring decisions to be based upon arrests that do not result in convictions.

I think it would be helpful for this answer to distinguish this circumstance from circumstances in which unintentional disparate-impact discrimination is prohibited : https://www.justice.gov/crt/fcs/T6Manual7

@Jen Too big of a bite for me to take on. Maybe someone else is hot to trot.
